# FileNotFoundException sometimes when launching application

Tags: c#, wpf

for automatic update of my WPF application, I've this strategy :

- (1) process.exe starts
- process.exe looks for update => there's an update
- process.exe makes a copy of itself => process_copy.exe
- process.exe launch process_copy.exe with "update" parameters
- process.exe exits
- (2) process_copy.exe starts
- process_copy.exe see the "update" parameters, download update to process.exe
- process_copy.exe launch process.exe
- process_copy.exe exits
- process.exe starts

Note that my application use a dll.

this strategy is working, except some times (not everytime) when the application is launched at startup in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Sometimes it crashes at (2), with a

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
>     Message="Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedWinapi, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

I don't understand why it can crash.
If it can start in (1), why can't it (sometimes) start in (2) ?

Do someone have an explanation ?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use ClickOnce?

Comment: The reason is that it's a very simple application, and doesn't need a big update system.
But I can't understand why it can have a filenotfoundexception whereas the file is here ...

Comment: Using ClickOnce seems a lot simpler than making your own update system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, I've integrated this dll in my application, so I have no dll more ... that's ugly but working

Answer (score 0):

Option 0: Do you know the dependencies of 'ManagedWinapi'?  If not, use Reflector to determine them.  There may be an issue with finding one of those?

Option 1:
Try running ProcessMonitor to determine what specifically your application is missing occasionally.  ("or one of its dependencies" - that coulod be any number of things.

Option 2:
It's an intermittent issue.  Is your copy operation asynchronous, or are you absolutely sure that "process_copy.exe" PLUS whatever additional components you may be copying have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve** event to see what and where its looking for the file